# BigQuery connecting from GSheet without enabling API every time

Tags: api, google-sheets, google-bigquery

I have some scripts running from GSheet getting data from BigQuery. However, in order to make the files run, I need to manually enable the API every time for a given sheet. 
So the question is: How to enable API within the code, so that if I share the GSheet or make a copy I don't have to go to the script editor and enable the API from there?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am a huge fan of this particular use of the Google ecosystem, so I'm happy to help get others up and running using GSheets with BigQuery! Hopefully it is working well for you!

When sharing the sheet with others, there is no need to alter anything in the script editor at all. The scripts should run and query BigQuery without issue; this has been my experience at least. The obvious caveat to this is that the users you share it with must have access to the Google Developer Project that the BigQuery instance is associated with.

However, when copying the sheet, I do not believe it is possible to have it replicate the connection. This is because when the file is copied, it becomes associated with a new Google Developer Project. Thus, you have to go into the script editor, then go to Resources > Developers Console Project and change the project listed to the one in which you have BigQuery enabled.

Hopefully this helps! Sorry I don't have better news for you!

Comment: Thank you andre622. Is there maybe anything that can be done from within google script to make the enabling the API automatic?

Comment: Unfortunately, at least in your case, Google made it clear than whenever a new apps script project is created (which is what you are doing when you copy a sheet with a script in the editor), that new apps script project creates its' own, new, unique project in the Developer's Console. This is control authorization. See link [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/authorization#using_a_different_google_developers_console_project)